# Changing color in one column based on the value in another

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am new to vba and I am attempting to create a module that takes the value in column C ( which should say "In Progress")and makes it "neutral" colored if the value within the same row on column E is less than 0.5(or 50%) but I have not had any luck. I have a counter variable made to keep track of the row I'm on. Any advice would be helpful and if you could recommend me to a good source for learning vba I would really appreciate it.

```
If Range("C1") = "Status" Then

    Range("C1").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

        If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "In Progress" Then
            If Range("E" & counter).Value < 0.5 Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Style = "Neutral"
            End If
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 13

        counter = counter + 1

    Loop

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in Conditional Formatting feature in Excel?

Comment: Thank you for responding. It does seem simple enough, however this is for multiple sheets with about 300 rows each, so using a module would help cut out time for such a tedious task.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim c As Range, sht As WorkSheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet
If sht.Range("C1").Value = "Status" Then

    Set c = sht.Range("C2")

    Do Until Len(c.Value) = 0

        If c.Value = "In Progress" Then
            If c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "E").Value < 0.5 Then
                c.Style = "Neutral"
            Else
                c.Style = "Normal"
            End If
        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    sht.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 13

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem and this fits for you, you could try this. The following code searches for value "In Progress" in the entire column A, and if this value is found and the same row cell in column C is less than 0.5, then sets the color of the cell in column A to "no fill".

```
Sub searchValue()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Cells
        If cell = "In Progress" Then
            If cell.Offset(0, 2) < 0.5 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This helped me better understand my problem.